# Python Jedi AutoComplete Without Ctrl-Space

Tags: vim, python-jedi

Jedi in Vim allows one to autocomplete in Python by pressing Ctrl-Space.

Is there a way for the autocomplete to just work automatically without having to press Ctrl-Space to bring up the intellisense/autocomplete box?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm too lazy to write up a good answer, you can for example use supertab as an additional vim plugin or reconfigure the key to something else than Ctrl-Space. If you really don't want to press any buttons. There's other libraries than jedi-vim that also use jedi, like youcompleteme, deoplete-jedi etc.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Yeah, unfortunately, YouCompleteMe is not so straightforward to configure on a Mac (works just fine on my Linux box). Anyway, maybe I'll check out those Jedi alternatives you mentioned. Apologies for the n00bery on my part, I'm just starting to get into Vim and what not.

Answer (score 0):

The [AutoComplPop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) automatically opens the popup menu for any (built-in or custom) completion. (You need to configure it, though.) It's apparently not actively maintained any longer, but it still works and I use it occasionally.

As others already mentioned in the comments, other (big) plugins ship with the auto-completion feature, but you then get all sorts of unrelated functionality, too.